# Should all FOREIGN KEYS have a drop down option using INSERT GUI

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have a table(APPOINTMENT)  with 3 foreign keys.
These are Staff_ID, Dentist_ID, and Patient_ID.
When using the GUI INSERT function I noted only the patient_ID field has a drop down for the patients with the patient table.
However the Staff_ID and Dentist_ID the user can enter any value.

Should all foreign key fields not have a drop down for existing entries in respective tables?

[image: Table, mySQL on phpMyAdmin]

EDIT- adding additional images

[image: Fig 2 - The Foreign Keys are marked with a silver key]

[image: Fig 3- Relational view of primary and foreign keys]

[image: Fig 4- Relational veiw 2]

Comment: The only reason I can think of off hand for your insert page to look like this is if Staff_ID and Dentist_ID aren't truly set as foreign keys. Can you post a picture of the Designer tab (which is a top-level tab of the database page) or Relationship view (which you can see from the table's Structure tab), or by showing us the SQL statement for the foreign keys (which you can easily generate from the Export tab)?

Comment: Hi, I have added images of relational views, I can't see why in Fig 4 it only shows the Patient_ID and Dentist_ID foreign key (FK) constraints as opposed to Fig 3 which shows all primary and FKs

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to add the FK again I noted the following error which for some reason I had not noted previously:

> MySQL error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails

The issue in my case was the field I was converting to a FK already had a value in it that had no corresponding value in the primary key column it referencing. There is a good explanation of the error [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)